# Strange dates in plotting graph in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe, julia-plots

I get some strange result when I try plotting a DataFrame.
When I plot the starting graph it works great.

```
using DataFrames, XLSX, StatsPlots, Indicators

df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("Demo-sv.xlsx", "Blad3")...)
df[!, :Closeprice] .= Float64.(df.Closeprice)
```

Example of the data

```
1×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Date       │ Closeprice │
│     │ Any        │ Float64    │
├─────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 2019-05-03 │ 169.96     │
```

Then I plot the data

```
@df df plot(df.Date, df.Closeprice)
```

[image: The DataFrame graph]

But when I try to add a new plot (a simple moving average (`sma()`)), I get some really strange result. The dates isn't correct anymore, and the graph looks weird. I don't know if my new plot is somehow overwriting the original even if it should add to the existing plot?

I have tried to use both functions down below to add the new plot, but both gives the same result.

```
plot!(sma(df.Closeprice, n=200))
plot!(sma(sort(df, :Date).Closeprice, n=200))
```

But I have gotten the same result, where the graph just looks strange. And I don't know what is causing this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you are plotting your new plot vs the date starting from `Date(1)` which is `0001-01-01`.
You need to plot `plot!(df.Date, sma(df.Closeprice, n=200))`.

By the way, calling the entry `Date` is not best practice, as `Date` is already the name of the DataType.

Comment: So my new plot didn't use the df.date, instead used a default date? And yes of course I should change the ```Date``` entry to something better.

Comment: Yes, I guess your new plot was something like 
`plot!(Date.(collect(1:length(df.Closeprice))), sma(df.Closeprice, n=200))`

Comment: Sorry, actually it is more like: `plot!(Date(1) .+ Dates.Day.(collect(1:length(df.Closeprice))), sma(df.Closeprice,n=200))`. Plotting without any x value increases the x value by 1 day for every y value. `Day(2)` is however year 2